# Hover is not working on IE11 and Edge

Tags: css, hover, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I am trying to make iframe expanded and shrank when the mouse pointer is on the iframe by using media query.

However, it is not working, but, when the mouse point is on the frame border then it is expanded and shrank.

Dose anyone know how to fix this on IE11 and Edge?

Also, there is limitation that I can not use jQuery outside the iframe because of same origin policy. So, I might have to fix css to implement this animation.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
  iframe[id^=sidebanner]{
    width: 80px;
  }
  iframe#sidebanner{
    right: 0;
  }
  iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -o-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;

  }
  @media all and (max-width: 2500px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 50%;
    }

  }
  @media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 55%;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 60%;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 750px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 65%;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 700px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 70%;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 650px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 75%;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
  </style>

  </head>
  <body>

  <iframe id="sidebanner" src="" frameborder="1" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="top: 0px; height: 100%; right: 0px;"></iframe>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Did you check your javascript errors by pressing F12 to the developer console?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you can use jquery to add a class `hover` that will contain the css needed to extend the `iframe`.

```
$('#sidebanner').hover(
       function(){ $(this).addClass('hover') },
       function(){ $(this).removeClass('hover') }
)
```

With this function we simply tell to add a class `hover` to our `#sidebanner` id

You also need to add css to the `hover` class. This will be the same css used in `iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover`. Also add the `hover` class to your `@media` queries.

```
.hover {
    -webkit-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -o-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
  }
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/c9syw731/2/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But, there is limitation that I can not use jQuery outside the iframe. So, I might have to fix css to implement this animation.

Comment: from what I researched , I couldn't find a method for the `:hover` to work on the `iframe` on IE / Edge without jquery

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate your help. I also could not find any solution for this.

Comment: Just wondering... Do you think this is a bug on IE11? @djgroup

Answer (score 0):

I added and remove "hoveranimation" class on hover and mouse leave event correspondingly.

and added a "#sidebanner.hoveranimation" to css

```js
$('#sidebanner').hover(function() {
      $(this).addClass('hoveranimation');
    });

    $('#sidebanner').mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('hoveranimation');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
  iframe[id^=sidebanner]{
    width: 80px;
     !important;
  }
  iframe#sidebanner{
    right: 0;
  }
  iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
   

  }
  @media all and (max-width: 2500px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 50%;
    }

  }
  @media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 55%;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 60%;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 750px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 65%;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 700px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 70%;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 650px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 75%;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    iframe[id^=sidebanner]:hover{
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
  #sidebanner.hoveranimation {
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -o-transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
    transition: width ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
  
  </style>

  </head>
  <body>

  <iframe id="sidebanner" src="" frameborder="1" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="top: 0px; height: 100%; right: 0px;"></iframe>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Unfortunately, we can only use CSS to hover iframe for security reason. So.... do you think you can do without jQuery?